# Jquery loader only works for the first request

Tags: jquery, ajax, loader

I'm actually trying to had an 'ergonomic touch' for my app, so I got 3 links that get html content and load it into a div. All works fine except the loader which only appears during the first request.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#loader')
.hide()  // hide it initially
.ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
})
.ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});

var uri_segment = "<?=$this->uri->segment(3);?>";


$('#editTeam').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');



    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        async : true,
        url : "<?=base_url().'ajax/team/get_editTeam/';?>"+uri_segment,
        dataType : "html",
        success : function(data){
                $('#divPage').html(data);

        }
    });

    return false;
});

$('#editRights').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');


    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');

    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        async : false,
        url : "<?=base_url().'ajax/team/get_editRights/';?>"+uri_segment,
        dataType : "html",
        success : function(data){
                $('#divPage').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});


$('#addMember').click(function (e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');


    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');



        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            async : false,
            url : "<?=base_url().'ajax/team/get_addMember/'.$this->uri->segment(3);?>",
            dataType : "html",
            success : function(data){
                $('#divPage').html(data);

            }
        });
        return false;
});


});
```

Comment: Any JS errors in the console?

Comment: No :/ All is fine, same for ajax requests

Comment: I added a log in ajaxStart and ajaxStop, it works fine. Maybe it's due to the cache ?

Comment: Try logging the value of `this`.

Comment: working fine... got the normals display:blocks / none

Comment: Could you post the HTML source that you see on the page and not the PHP that might shed some light?

Comment: Actually, relooking at your code... you should only attach ajaxStart/ajaxStop to the document object with newer versions of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `ajaxStart`/`ajaxStop` onto the document. [Per the documentation, as of 1.8 you should only bind it to document.](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

```
$('#loader').hide();

$('document')
  .ajaxStart(function() {
    $('#loader').show();
  })
  .ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
  });
```